# Masonry JS stacking issues only on initial page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've read so many posts about this, but nothing is working! Here's a quick .gif of what's happening - http://benadelt.com/tweet-grid.gif

I'm using Masonry and loading the script like so:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
     var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
     var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
       // options
       columnWidth: '.item',
       itemSelector: '.item',
       transitionDuration: '0.2s'
    });
  });
```

I'm using the .item class on multiple elements on multiple pages to Masonrize various grids, and they all work perfectly except one in which I'm trying to create a grid of embedded tweets (Bootstrap):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="masonry">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="tweet-box">
          <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-conversation="none" lang="en"><p><a href="https://twitter.com/geofeedia">@geofeedia</a> can't wait for the ability to do geo-fenced and hashtag/keyword searches in geofeedia ... get it to us quick ! <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23smem&src=hash">#smem</a></p>— Patrice Cloutier (@patricecloutier) <a href="https://twitter.com/patricecloutier/statuses/368417800307499008">August 16, 2013</a>    </blockquote>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While Masonry is working on that grid, on initial load it's not spaced properly. This was happening with my other grids before until I called on window load instead of doc ready.

Here's a .gif of a grid that's working with exactly the same markup, except inside the grid is just text rather than the embedded tweet: http://benadelt.com/other-grid.gif

Ideas?

Comment: Call in ready. Must work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're saying?

Comment: I mean call in on document.ready.

Comment: Try to give a min-height to the tweet-box or load masonry when tweets are loaded.